# Максимальное значение SEQUENCE

Tags: sql, postgresql

Здравствуйте!

Почему pgAdmin3 при добавлении в таблицу поля id, типа serial, создает SEQUENCE с MAXVALUE равным 9223372036854775807 т.е. под bigint. Тип id же выставляет integer.

Не грозит ли это проблемами при достижении ограничения типа integer?

Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: это 2^63 - 1. Вполне MAX_INT на 64 бита системах.

Comment: Значит везде данные по хранимому диапазону типов указаны для 32 битных систем

Comment: `serial` - это как раз только 32-битное поле. 64-битное - `bigserial` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Интересно, провёл эксперимент:

```
melkij=# create table testserial (id serial not null primary key, num integer not null);
CREATE TABLE
melkij=# alter sequence testserial_id_seq maxvalue 9223372036854775807 restart with 2147483646;
ALTER SEQUENCE
melkij=# insert into testserial (num) values(1);
INSERT 0 1
melkij=# insert into testserial (num) values(2);
INSERT 0 1
melkij=# insert into testserial (num) values(3);
ОШИБКА:  целое вне диапазона
melkij=# select * from testserial;
     id     | num 
------------+-----
 2147483646 |   1
 2147483647 |   2
(2 rows)

melkij=#
```

При достижении предела значений для `int`, `postgresql` отказывается вставлять новые данные. Напомню, что `serial` - это 32-битное поле. 64-битное - `bigserial`

Ещё интересный момент:

```
melkij=# select nextval('testserial_id_seq'::regclass);
  nextval   
------------
 2147483649
(1 row)

melkij=# select nextval('testserial_id_seq'::regclass);
  nextval   
------------
 2147483650
(1 row)

melkij=# alter sequence testserial_id_seq restart with 9223372036854775806;ALTER SEQUENCE
melkij=# select nextval('testserial_id_seq'::regclass);
       nextval       
---------------------
 9223372036854775806
(1 row)

melkij=# select nextval('testserial_id_seq'::regclass);
       nextval       
---------------------
 9223372036854775807
(1 row)

melkij=# select nextval('testserial_id_seq'::regclass);
ОШИБКА:  функция nextval достигла максимума для последовательности "testserial_id_seq" (9223372036854775807)

melkij=# alter sequence testserial_id_seq restart with 9223372036854775806 NO MAXVALUE;
ALTER SEQUENCE
melkij=# select nextval('testserial_id_seq'::regclass);       nextval       
---------------------
 9223372036854775806
(1 row)

melkij=# select nextval('testserial_id_seq'::regclass);
       nextval       
---------------------
 9223372036854775807
(1 row)

melkij=# select nextval('testserial_id_seq'::regclass);
ОШИБКА:  функция nextval достигла максимума для последовательности "testserial_id_seq" (9223372036854775807)
melkij=#
```

Как видно, сам счётчик сиквенса - всегда 64-битный. 9223372036854775807 - предельное значение для него хоть с MAXVALUE, хоть без него.